# Регистрация Instagram аккаунтов через requests python 3

Tags: python-3.x, requests, instagram, регистрация

```
import requests 
import time
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

headers ={
'Host': 'www.instagram.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
'Cookie': '',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'TE': 'Trailers'
}
data = {
'client_id':'W8AvBQ1ALAAEbfRj5lRKWtgBiO1iL',
'first_name':'Vladimir Astafeev',   
'opt_into_one_tap':'false',
'password':'3gfs41tgr6r2rt',    
'email':'cadfegfsf1hgad12@gmail.com',
'username':'vladimirastafeev5640'   
}

url_reg = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/'
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    req = session.get(url_reg)

    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken':req.cookies['csrftoken']})
    time.sleep(2)
    registration = session.post(url_reg, data = data, allow_redirects = True )
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken':registration.cookies['csrftoken']})
    cookies = registration.cookies
    registration_json = json.loads(registration.text)
    print(registration_json)
```

Выводит это:

```
{'password': '3gfs41tgr6r2rt', 'email': 'cadfegfsf1hgad12@gmail.com', 'username': 'vladimirastafeev5640', 'opt_into_one_tap': 'false', 'tos_version': 'row', 'seamless_login_enabled': '1', 'client_id': 'W8AvBQ1ALAAEbfRj5lRKWtgBiO1iL', 'first_name': 'Vladimir Astafeev'}

{'status': 'ok', 'username_suggestions': ['cadfegfsf1hgad12', 'vladimirastafeev3', 'vladimirastafeev36', 'vladimirastafeev422', 'vladimirastafeev8599', 'vladimirastafeev2', 'vladimirastafeev57', 'vladimirastafeev157', 'vladimirastafeev9779', 'vladimirastafeev1', 'vladimirastafeev50'], 'account_created': False, 'dryrun_passed': True}
```

Вот мне интересен вопрос как можно зарегать акк instagram с помощью python 3, пробовал с Selenium, но меня банят - пишет, что ip открытый и сразу бан.

Comment: 'client_id' откуда брать нужно?

Comment: официальное api это?

Answer (score 1):

url_reg у тебя не правильный вот замени url_reg на это

```
url_reg = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/'
```